# autoloader for loading classes won't work as expected

Tags: php, autoloader

recently i started working with OOP and i created a classLoader to load the classes i use.. so i made this class and worked with it ( local ) and all went fine. But when i uploaded everything to my webhost it stopped working. i get the following error when i visit a page where the loader needs to load a class..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Class "formhandler" could not be autoloaded from:
    /var/www/vhosts/***.nl/httpdocs/admin/lib/formhandler.php' in 
    /var/www/vhosts/***.nl/httpdocs/admin/index.php:30 Stack trace:
        #0 /var/www/vhosts/***.nl/httpdocs/admin/index.php(109): __autoload('formhandler')
        #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/***.nl/httpdocs/admin/index.php on line 30
```

the code for my autoloader is as followed..

```
function __autoload($className) 
      {
        // get the base dir.
          $base = dirname(__FILE__);

          // get path
          $path = $className;


          $file = $base . "/lib/" . $path . '.php';       


          //if exists get file else throw error
          if (file_exists($file)) 
          {
              require $file;      
          }
          else 
          {
              error_log('Class "' . $className . '" could not be autoloaded');
              throw new Exception('Class "' . $className . '" could not be autoloaded from: ' . $file); 
          }
      }
```

Comment: If your local env is windows, keep in mind that Unix/Linux file/path names are case sensitive.

Comment: no i work on osx. if i see the error i think it couldn;t load the class but i have moved everything like the way it works local..

Comment: try echo out $file and make sure it matches

Comment: if i echo $file i get 

/var/www/vhosts/***.nl/httpdocs/admin/lib/formhandler.php so the path is correct as far as i can see.. at least the formhandler.php is in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the production path of the `formhandler` class. I guarantee there will be a difference between it and `/var/www/vhosts/.nl/httpdocs/admin/lib/formhandler.php`. Correct it.

Comment: i compared the two and locally ( the one that works ) i get /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectx/admin/lib/formhandler.php

and with the webhost i get /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.nl/httpdocs/admin/lib/formhandler.php

Comment: That does not match you comments above. You said the file was `FormHandler.php`. As such, the path is indeed *wrong* (incorrect case).

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. i had new formhandler(); but instead i had to use new FormHandler(); in my script because my webhost didn;t find it.. verry annoying but it works now!

Comment: so was the actual filename FormHander.php or formhandler.php

Comment: Ok that sounds like @Alex Wright post was correct, it was a unix case sensitive issue.

Comment: You really shouldn't answer you own questions. Especially when the other comments and answers lead you to the correct answer.